# Moving picturebox according to the score of the dice

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am new to visual basic and am needing some help. I am creating a board game where you have to roll a dice and depending on the side it lands on, the picture box moves accordingly. I have labels put together in a square shape making up a look alike grid that is 5 rows and 10 columns. So far, I have the part for when the player clicks the button "Rouler" they get a randomized side of the dice. I would like for each time the dice is rolled it moves along the grid accordingly to the number the dice has picked.

```
Public Class frm1
Dim Rand As New Random 
Dim Dé(5) As Image

Private Sub btnRouler_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRouler.Click
    Dim n As Integer 
    n = Rand.Next(4)
    PictureBoxDé.Image = Dé(n) 
End Sub

Private Sub frm1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dé(0) = My.Resources._11 
    Dé(1) = My.Resources._2  
    Dé(2) = My.Resources._3  
    Dé(3) = My.Resources._4  
    Dé(4) = My.Resources._5  
    Dé(5) = My.Resources._6
```

Comment: I am having a difficult time “visualizing” what you describe. Can you show a picture of what you have and what you are wanting to do? I am not following what you mean by.. _” … and depending on the side it lands on, the picture box moves accordingly.”_ … ? …

Comment: I cant manage to attache a picture, the file is too big... What I mean is for example if the player (picturebox) is on the first square of the grid and the dice lands on six, the player (picturebox) will move six to the left. But since its a grid, on the next line itll need to move to the right.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are saying you have 50 labels arranged in 10 columns and 5 rows. The De array contains the dice images.

This is one approach. Make a small class called `Player`. When you add a second player you will see the value of this.

You will need an array of the labels, indexes 0-49.

When you roll the die, you choose the appropriate image form the `De` array. Next, you clear the `Player1.Token` from the `CurrentPosition` Label. You also increase the players current position by n + 1. If he rolls a `1` (`De(0)`) you add one to n to move 1 space. Finally, you add a the `Player1.Token` to the label at the new position.

```
Public Class Player
    Public Property Token As Image
    Public Property CurrentPosition As Integer

    Public Sub New(Pic As Image)
        Token = Pic
        CurrentPosition = 0
    End Sub

End Class

Private Player1 As Player

Private Dé(5) As Image
Private LabelArray(49) As Label


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    LabelArray = {Label1, Label2, Label3, Label4} 'etc.
    Player1 = New Player(Image.FromFile("Dog.png"))
    Dé(0) = My.Resources._11
    Dé(1) = My.Resources._2
    Dé(2) = My.Resources._3
    Dé(3) = My.Resources._4
    Dé(4) = My.Resources._5
    Dé(5) = My.Resources._6

End Sub

Private Sub btnRouler_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRouler.Click
    Dim n As Integer
    n = Rand.Next(6) 'Non negative integer, one less than the parameter - in this case 0 to 5
    PictureBoxDé.Image = Dé(n)
    Player1.CurrentPosition += n + 1
    LabelArray(Player1.CurrentPosition).Image = Player1.Token
End Sub
```